# Linux Rails Gem Install Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Does anyone know what's happening here?

```
root@ip-172-31-5-114:/home/bitnami/htdocs/kicksharer/kickscraper# gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.0.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.0.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
root@ip-172-31-5-114:/home/bitnami/htdocs/kicksharer/kickscraper# bundle show rails-5.0.0.1
Could not find gem 'rails-5.0.0.1'.
```

Any suggestions for troubleshooting would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why? What does the `bundle show` documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `gem install rails` it installs it on your system.  You need to make sure rails is specified in your gem file and then `bundle install` in order to install those gems in the bundle. (It should use the already installed gems on your system)

Comment: Also, you cannot do `bundle show GEM-VERSION`, so after fiddling with the `Gemfile` run `bundle show rails`.